# Component not changing state in React

Tags: reactjs

In my app I'm trying to change the state of route when I click submit in my SignIn component. I want to pass onRouteChange as props. Is the function not being passed to the other component?

App:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { route: "signed-out" };
  }
  onRouteChange = () => {
    this.setState({ route: "home" });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div class='main'>
        {this.state.route === "signed-out" ? (
          <div>
            <SignIn onRouteChange={this.onRouteChange}/>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div>
            <SignOut  />
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

SignIn Component:

```
    const SignIn = ({ onRouteChange }) => {
      return (
        <div>
          <form>
            <div>Sign In</div>
            <div>Email</div>
            <input type='email' />
            <div>Password</div>
            <input type='password' />
            <input onClick={onRouteChange} type='submit' />
          </form>
        </div>
      );
    };
```

Comment: Looks like you passed `onRouteChange` to `<SignOut>`, but not the `<SignIn>` component you included.

Comment: I changed it but I am still having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the function to `SignOut` component but trying to use it in `SignIn` component.

Your `App.js` file should have this instead:

```
...
<div>
    <SignIn onRouteChange={this.onRouteChange} />
</div>
) : (
<div>
    <SignOut />
</div>
...
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer! I can't believe I didn't see that. Weirdly though, I'm still having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this, I'd bind the `onRouteChange` to `this` in the constructor and redefine the `onRouteChange` as such:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { route: "signed-out" };
    this.onRouteChange = this.onRouteChange.bind(this); // new
  }

  onRouteChange() {
    this.setState({ route: "home" });
  };

  // rest of your code
```

Now with that function binded to `this` your code here `<SignIn onRouteChange={this.onRouteChange}/>` should now work.

Comment: Thank you. I tried this out but it didn't work.